# Impala SQL limit by column

Tags: sql, impala

I have a query that ends with:

```
GROUP BY supervisor,
     agent,
     task
ORDER BY supervisor,
     agent,
     'task_count'
```

What I'm running into is that each agent can have upwards of 100 tasks, and I'd like to only list the top 20 for each agent (by task_count). If I use LIMIT, that limits the entire results list to 20. Is there a way to only have LIMIT apply to the agent column? Thanks!

Comment: You should show the rest of your query.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can use `row_number()`, though:

```
select . . . 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by agent order by task_count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

If `task_count` is being calculated, then do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.agent, t.task, count(*) as task_count,
             row_number() over (partition by agent order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.agent, t.task
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

Comment: I think you need a range for the count(*) to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your platform but on DB2 it looks like this:

```
select -- stuff
  supervisor, agent, ordn
from (
  SELECT -- stuff
     supervisor, agent,
     row_number() over (partition by supervisor, agent order by count(*) RANGE   BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as ordn
  GROUP BY supervisor, agent
) x
where ordn <= 20
order by  supervisor, agent, ordn
```

Note you need the range because by default the range is current and unbounded preceding.